# Can fatwire run on tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, fatwire

Currently running fatwire on weblogic, would it be easy to port it to to tomcat, does it require J2EE? If not tomcat how about Jboss?

Comment: I went to look at their Web site for a clue on how to help you. If the product, whatever it is, is as useful as their Web site, you'd be best off ditching it.

Comment: I do not entirely disagree with you, however that call is made by others....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both Tomcat and JBoss are supported

Comment: Does it require J2EE and hence Jboss? Or will pure tomcat do?

Comment: Pure tomcat will do. Oracle have a matrix of supported software on their home page.

Answer (score 1):

Accoding to the documentation, you can run Fatwire on **Tomcat**, **WebSphere**, **Weblogic**, **Jboss**, **Resin**. I've personally seen Fatwire running on Tomcat, Weblogic, WebSphere quite successfully.

You can run on Tomcat, because the main components are JSPs and you may not need to use an app server with EJB container.

Answer (score 1):

It should be fairly straightforward to move Content Server from weblogic to tomcat or jboss, assuming that the location of the CS install files do not change, and nor does the hostname:port that it listens on. ContentServer uses only servlets, filters, jsps, and jdbc datasources. There is no EJB requirement. It is certified to run on tomcat and jboss, and in the past also ran on resin.

There will be a .war file under <INSTALLDIR>/ominstallinfo/app that can be copied to your (for example) tomcat/webapps directory. You will need to add a datasource configuration to tomcat's server.xml so that CS can find the database, and you can copy the database driver to tomcat's lib folder.

Be cautious about future upgrades/patching though, the patch/upgrade installer looks to the omininstallinfo for an omproduct.ini which contains some installation metadata, such as the application server location. This info is used during upgrade for inserting new catalogs, and deploying the new .war/.ear file. The omproduct.ini will still reference the location of the old weblogic and it's, and so patching/upgrading may fail.

If you are moving to a new host:port or changing the location of the CS install files as well as switching application server, then it'e best to contact Support because it could get hairy.

Phil